# To show meanings of words on hovering which is to be used as a post editing tool in MT system

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, tooltip

I am building post editing tool for a Machine Translation System.

I need to add a functionality wherein if a user hovers over the source text words it gets the meaning of that particular word or phrase in the target language in a tooltip on the JSP web page, for which I have to maintain a hash map for storing the words and its corresponding meanings , but I am not able to  integrate the tooltip functionality with hash map .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over map and put tooltip value in [title attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp)

```
<%for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();
  %><input type="text" value="<%=key%>" title="<%=value%>">
<%}%>
```

> The title attribute specifies extra information about an element.
>
> The information is most often shown as a tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element.

Comment: I had to ask one more thing, that where to store the map containing dictionary, should I store it in the servlet program and send it as a response to the jsp page or what else can I do, please help

Comment: Basically yes, you can return it using a method as `public Map<String, String> getTranslationMap()`